# A Special Property of Finite Probability Space.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

My friend asked me this question (which he did not know the solution to).

**QUESTION:** Let $(\Omega, 2^\Omega, P)$ be a finite probability space.
Let $f_1,\ldots, f_k\in \mathbb F_2[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ be $k$ polynomials. Suppose there exist real numbers $c_1,\ldots, c_k$ such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k c_iP(f_i(A_1,\ldots, A_n))\geq 0
$$
whenever each $A_i$ is chosen to be either $\Omega$ or $\emptyset$.
Then the above equation holds no matter what the events $A_i$'s are chosen to be.

I am quite stumped here. Can somebody see what to do?

**Clarification:**
To clarify what is meant by $f_i(A_1,\ldots, A_k)$:

First, given two events $A$ and $B$ in $\Omega$, we write $A+B$ to mean $A\cup B$ and $AB$ to mean $A\cap B$. Now suppose, for example, we have $f=x_1x_2+x_3^2x_4\in \mathbb F_2[x_1, \ldots, x_4]$, then $$
f(A_1, \ldots, A_4)=(A_1A_2)+(A_3A_3A_4)=(A_1\cap A_2)\cup (A_3\cap A_4)
$$

Comment: How do you define $P(f(A_1,\dots,A_n))$? After all $f(A_1,\dots,A_n)$ will not be an element of $\Omega$ in general. What am I missing?

Comment: @PhoemueX It is interpretted as follows: First, given two events $A$ and $B$ in $\Omega$, we write $A+B$ to mean $A\cup B$ and $AB$ to mean $A\cap B$. This is a standard practice in probability theory. Now suppose, for example, we have $f=x_1x_2+x_3^2x_4\in \mathbb F_2[x_1, \ldots, x_4]$, then $f(A_1, \ldots, A_4)=(A_1A_2)+(A_3A_3A_4)=(A_1\cap A_2)\cup (A_3\cap A_4)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that your question is more a question of Linear Algebra than anything else.

What we are doing is to associate to each monomial $x_1^{k_1} \cdots x_n^{k_n}$ the map $\chi_{A_1}^{k_1} \cdots \chi_{A_n}^{k_n}$, where the powers do not matter (it matters only if $k_i = 0$ or $k_i \neq 0$) since $\chi_{A_i}$ only attains the values $0,1$.

This means the resulting function can always be written in the form

$$
\sum_I \alpha_I \chi_{A_I},
$$
where the sum runs over multiindices $I \in \{0,1\}^n$ with $\alpha_I \in \Bbb{R}$ and $$\chi_{A_I}:= \prod_{j=1}^n \chi_{A_j}^{I_j}.$$

I now claim that

$$\chi_{A_I} \in {\rm span}(\chi_{A_1^{\varepsilon_1}} \cdots \chi_{A_n^{\varepsilon_n}} \mid \varepsilon_1, \dots, \varepsilon_n \in \{0,1\}) =: V \quad \forall I \in \{0,1\}^n, \quad (\dagger)$$
where we define $A_i^0 := A_i^c$ and $A_i^1 := A_i$.

This is shown by induction on $n \in \Bbb{N}$. For $n=1$, the claim is clear, since

1. For $I = 0$, we have $\chi_{A_I} \equiv 1 = \chi_{A_1} + \chi_{A_1^c}$.
2. For $I = 1$, we have $\chi_{A_I} = \chi_{A_1}$.

If $(\dagger)$ is true for some $n \in \Bbb{N}$, then for $I \in \{0,1\}^{n+1}$, there are two cases:

1. $I_{n+1} = 0$. In this case, $\chi_{A_I} = \chi_{A_J}$, where $J = I|_{\{1, \dots, n\}}$ is the "truncated" multiindex. But the induction hypothesis yields $\chi_{A_J} = \sum_\varepsilon \alpha_\varepsilon \chi_{A_1^{\varepsilon_1}} \cdots \chi_{A_n^{\varepsilon_n}}$ for suitable coefficients $\alpha_\varepsilon$. Hence,
   $$
   \chi_{A_J} = \sum_\varepsilon \alpha_\varepsilon [\chi_{A_1^{\varepsilon_1}} \cdots \chi_{A_n^{\varepsilon_n}} (\chi_{A_{n+1}}  + \chi_{A_{n+1}^c})].
   $$
   Using distributivity, this yields $\chi_{A_I} \in V$.
2. $I_{n+1} = 1$. Take $J$ as in the first case and note that

$$
\chi_{A_I} = \chi_{A_J}  \cdot \chi_{A_{n+1}}= \sum_\varepsilon \alpha_\varepsilon \chi_{A_1^{\varepsilon_1}} \cdots \chi_{A_n^{\varepsilon_n}} \chi_{A_{n+1}} \in V
$$

All in all, this shows that we can write

$$
g := \sum c_i f_i (A_1, \dots, A_n) = \sum_{\varepsilon \in \{0,1\}^n} \alpha_\varepsilon \chi_{A_1^{\varepsilon_1}} \cdots \chi_{A_n^{\varepsilon_n}}
$$
for suitable coefficients $\alpha_\varepsilon \in \Bbb{R}$.

I claim that your hypothesis yields $\alpha_\varepsilon \geq 0$ for all $\varepsilon$.

Here, we use the fact that plugging in suitable $A_i \in \{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ and integrating yields a **dual basis** to the $\chi_{A_1^{\varepsilon_1}} \cdots A_n^{\varepsilon_n}$.

To see this, let $\varepsilon \in \{0,1\}^n$ be arbitrary. Set $A_i := \emptyset$ if $\varepsilon_i = 0$ and $A_i := \Omega$ if $\varepsilon_i = 1$. Then $\chi_{A_1^{\varepsilon_1}} \cdots \chi_{A_n^{\varepsilon_n}} \equiv 1$, but $\chi_{A_1^{\gamma_1}} \cdots \chi_{A_n^{\gamma_n}} \equiv 0$ for $\gamma \in \{0,1\}^n$ with $\gamma \neq \varepsilon$. Hence,

$$
0 \leq  \sum c_i P(f(A_1, \dots, A_n)) =\int g \, dP = \alpha_\varepsilon.
$$

With this, it is easy to see that the sum is positive for any choice of $A_1, \dots, A_n$.